# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, localhost, require-once

I'm trying to run my online site on my local machine. I stumbled upon a problem.

This is my htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes
#php_value include_path .:/home/sites/www.example.it/example.it/htdocs/conf/

php_value include_path .:/XAMPP/htdocs/conf/

php_value display_errors on
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 50M
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.it [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.it/ [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /common.*
   RewriteRule ^common/(.*) resources/media/common/$1

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /upload/img.*
   RewriteRule ^upload/img/(.*)$ wapp/ir.php?path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}   

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /upload.*
   RewriteRule ^upload/(.*) resources/upload/$1

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/google.*
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/common.*
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/upload.* 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/upload/img/.* 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wapp/ir.php 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wapp/index.php?url=$1
</IfModule>
```

The error I receive:

**Warning:** `require_once(conf.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\wapp\index.php on line 2`

**Fatal error:** `require_once(): Failed opening required 'conf.inc.php' (include_path='.:/XAMPP/htdocs/conf/') in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\wapp\index.php on line 2`

How can I solve it? Maybe it deals with the privileges of the xampp user ...

**edit:**

**getcwd() gives me** C:\XAMPP\htdocs\wapp

**conf.inc.php is located in:** C:\XAMPP\htdocs\conf\

**the require in index.php:** require_once("conf.inc.php");

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try `chdir(dirname(__FILE__))` this sets the relative path to the path of the file.
So `C:\XAMPP\htdocs\wapp\` becomes your "root directory" and therefore `config.inc.php` is the same as `C:\XAMPP\htdocs\wapp\config.inc.php`. If this still doesn't to the trick check your file paths

Edit:

You have to traverse there. Check the relative root of the project (`getcwd()`). I assume its `C:\XAMPP\htdocs\wapp\` you have to change your require to this:

`require_once ('../conf/conf.inc.php')` the `..` make you go up one directory

OK just do this:

`require_once("../conf/conf.inc.php");`

Comment: config.inc.php is in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\conf\config.inc.php\. Where I have to insert chdir(dirname(__FILE__))? Just before the require_once("conf.inc.php");?

Comment: then you got the whole concept wrong. You have to traverse there i update my answer

Comment: You're right about the project root. I've done the edit but I've the same error:

Warning: require_once(../conf.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\wapp\index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../conf.inc.php' (include_path='.:/XAMPP/htdocs/conf/') in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\wapp\index.php on line 2

Comment: show me what your `getcwd()` says, the location of the file you want to require and the `require` you do